# How to create a class document in an easy and standard way?

Tags: java, documentation

I'm a java developer and I want to document my project and it's classes in PDF format.
I want to know what is the best way to document my project which explain all of my classes and their inheritance relationships and their method in a visual view.
I've Googled about this but I just found something about code documentation in IDE like this:
http://www.edparrish.net/common/javadoc.html

Comment: This question appears to be asking for tool recommendations and thus off-topic, but if you'll give some more details about what you mean by "visual view" we might be able to help. My general recommendation would be to write good Javadocs and use one of the processors that can draw dependency diagrams based on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in my opinion, install a checkstyle, this tell you in code(with yellow warnings) if you are programming something wrong or name conventions, also says you if you are missing a javadoc.

Then with the javadoc done, you can create javadoc and export to html. Later if you want you can export html to PDF with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javadocs (if I am right). Drjava and any other Java IDE such as Eclipse lets you do that.

Comment: How to do that in Eclipse?

Comment: Project -> Generate Javadoc

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse , in which I would suggest to download and install checkstyle and use as guide on how to java doc correctly your files and packages.
good luck.